# Conversion of this sentence

Tags: grammar

in outliers

> But I ought to understand how limited the possibilities of a firm like his **were** to hire a boy of my antecedents. (*original*)
> But I ought to understand how limited the possibilities of a firm like his to hire a boy of my antecedents **were**.

Are these two sentences the same?
that is, Is it possible to separate the to-infinitive and the noun it modifies?

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning, but the second one has poor readability. An even better version has "were" here: "*...how limited the possibilities **were** of a firm like his...*"

Comment: thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing so is possible, and these sentences would normally be understood to have the same meaning. We often postpone lengthy elements in English sentences. This may be called extraposition, right-dislocation, etc. This site has [an "extraposition" tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extraposition) that includes several questions that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you for answer, your answer is very helpful.